# Why is Haskell throwing a 'cannot construct infinite type' error?

Tags: haskell, type-inference

I wrote the following code in Haskell to compute the dot product of two vectors, but cannot compile it due to the following error:

`cannot construct infinite type: a = [a] When generalising the type(s) for dot'`

```
dot :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a] -> a

[] `dot` [] = 0
x@[xi,xs] `dot` y@[yi,ys] = xi*yi + (xs `dot` ys)
```

I've taken a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795317/why-does-this-haskell-code-produce-the-infinite-type-error) in advance for guidance. As far as I can tell, the types are correct. x, y and the two []'s are lists, and the function returns a number.

What's wrong?

Comment: That's Haskell equivalent of Object Reference Not Set or Stack Overflow, you're going to be seeing it a lot ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're confusing the syntax for a two element list `[x, y]` with the syntax for splitting a list into the first element and the rest of the list `(x:y)`. Try this instead:

```
dot :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a] -> a

[] `dot` [] = 0
x@(xi:xs) `dot` y@(yi:ys) = xi*yi + (xs `dot` ys)
```

The `@` patterns are also unnecessary, btw.

Answer (score 8):

[Ganesh' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530610/why-is-haskell-throwing-a-cannot-construct-infinite-type-error/1530621#1530621) is spot on. Let me briefly elaborate on the meaning of an "infinite type".

`dot` has this type definition:

```
dot :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a] -> a
```

This means that `dot` takes two lists of `Num` elements and returns a `Num`. Your definition includes this line:

```
x@[xi,xs] `dot` y@[yi,ys] = xi*yi + (xs `dot` ys)
```

Since, as Ganesh points out, `[xi,xs]` is a list consisting of two elements, `xi` and `xs` should be `Num`s. Same for `yi` and `ys`. But then they are passed as arguments to `dot`:

```
xs `dot` ys
```

This means that `xs` and `ys` must be lists of `Num`s. That leads to a contradiction.

---

Another way to look at this, is to for a moment forget about the type definition of `dot`. This line,

```
x@[xi,xs] `dot` y@[yi,ys] = xi*yi + (xs `dot` ys)
```

states that `dot` takes two lists whose elements are appropriate arguments to `dot`. But the only way for that to make sense, is if these lists are *infinitely nested*. That is not allowed nor sensible.

Comment: @Stephan: Thanks for the explanation. I think that clears up why even the [xi:xs] notation failed, as the xs `dot` ys would imply that xs and ys are lists of lists...

Let me know if my interpretation is valid.

Comment: @Zaid: that is correct. If `xi :: a`, then `(xi:xs) :: [a]` and `[xi:xs] :: [[a]]`. Thus matching on `[xi:xs]` and then recursively passing `xs` will indeed lead to an *infinite type* error.