# Is it possible to define a list recursively in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

In several programming languages (including JavaScript, Python, and Ruby), it's possible to place a list inside itself, which can be useful when using lists to represent infinitely-detailed fractals. However, I tried doing this in Haskell, and it did not work as I expected:

```
--aList!!0!!0!!1 should be 1, since aList is recursively defined: the first element of aList is aList.
main = putStrLn $ show $ aList!!0!!0!!1

aList = [aList, 1]
```

Instead of printing `1`, the program produced this compiler error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( prog.hs, prog.o )

prog.hs:3:12:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t0 = [t0]
    In the expression: aList
    In the expression: [aList, 1]
    In an equation for `aList': aList = [aList, 1]
```

Is it possible to put an list inside itself in Haskell, as I'm attempting to do here?

Comment: what do you mean by 'placing an array inside itself'? just 2d-arrays? in Haskell list is the default data structure and you can have a list that contains other lists (of type [[a]])

Comment: @jev anArray is recursively defined, so `anArray!!0!!1` would be equivalent to `anArray!!0!!0!!1` or `anArray!!0!!0!!0!!1`. A recursively defined array is not the same as a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: This general idea is called ["tying the knot"](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tying_the_Knot) in Haskell.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, you can't.  First off, there's a slight terminological confusion: what you have there are *lists*, not arrays ([which Haskell also has](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array.html)) , although the point stands either way.  So then, as with all things Haskell, you must ask yourself: *what would the type of `aList = [aList, 1]` be*?

Let's consider the simpler case of `aList = [aList]`.  We know that `aList` must be a list of *something*, so `aList :: [α]` for some type `α`.  What's `α`?  As the type of the list elements, we know that `α` must be the type of `aList`; that is, `α ~ [α]`, where `~` represents type equality.  So `α ~ [α] ~ [[α]] ~ [[[α]]] ~ ⋯ ~ [⋯[α]⋯] ~ ⋯`.  This is, indeed, an infinite type, and Haskell forbids such things.

In the case of the value `aList = [aList, 1]`, you also have the restriction that `1 :: α`, but all that that lets us conclude is that there must be a `Num α` constraint (`Num α => [⋯[α]⋯]`), which doesn't change anything.

---

The obvious next three questions are:

1. Why do Haskell lists only contain one type of element?
2. Why does Haskell forbid infinite types?
3. What can I do about this?

Let's tackle those in order.

---

Number one: Why do Haskell lists only contain one type of element?  This is because of Haskell's type system.  Suppose you have a list of values of different types: `[False,1,2.0,'c']`.  What's the type of the function `someElement n = [False,1,2.0,'c'] !! n`?  There isn't one, because you couldn't know what type you'd get back.  So what could you do with that value, anyway?  You don't know anything about it, after all!

---

Number two: Why does Haskell forbid infinite types?  The problem with infinite types is that they don't add many capabilities (you can always wrap them in a new type; see below), and they make some genuine bugs type-check.  For example, [in the question "Why does this Haskell code produce the ‘infinite type’ error?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/795317/237428), the non-existence of infinite types precluded a buggy implementation of `intersperse` (and would have even without the explicit type signature).

---

Number three: What can I do about this?  If you want to fake an infinite type in Haskell, you must use a *recursive data type*.  The data type prevents the type from having a truly infinite expansion, and the explicitness avoids the accidental bugs mentioned above.  So we can define a newtype for an infinitely nested list as follows:

```
Prelude> newtype INL a = MkINL [INL a] deriving Show
Prelude> let aList = MkINL [aList]
Prelude> :t aList
aList :: INL a
Prelude> aList
MkINL [MkINL [MkINL [MkINL ^CInterrupted.
```

This got us our infinitely-nested list that we wanted—printing it out is never going to terminate—but none of the *types* were infinite.  (`INL a` is *isomorphic* to `[INL a]`, but it's not *equal* to it.  If you're curious about this, the difference is between [isorecursive types (what Haskell has) and equirecursive types (which allow infinite types).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type#Theory))

But note that this type isn't very useful; the only lists it contains are either infinitely nested things like `aList`, or variously nested collections of the empty list.  There's no way to get a base case of a value of type `a` into one of the lists:

```
Prelude> MkINL [()]

<interactive>:15:8:
    Couldn't match expected type `INL a0' with actual type `()'
    In the expression: ()
    In the first argument of `MkINL', namely `[()]'
    In the expression: MkINL [()]
```

So the list you want is an *arbitrarily* nested list.  The [99 Haskell Problems](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/H-99:_Ninety-Nine_Haskell_Problems) has a question about these, which requires defining a new data type:

```
data NestedList a = Elem a | List [NestedList a]
```

Every element of `NestedList a` is either a plain value of type `a`, or a list of more `NestedList a`s.  (This is the same thing as an arbitrarily-branching tree which only stores data in its leaves.)  Then you have

```
Prelude> data NestedList a = Elem a | List [NestedList a] deriving Show
Prelude> let aList = List [aList, Elem 1]
Prelude> :t aList
aList :: NestedList Integer
Prelude> aList
List [List [List [List ^CInterrupted.
```

You'll have to define your own lookup function now, and note that it will probably have type `NestedList a -> Int -> Maybe (NestedList a)`—the `Maybe` is for dealing with out-of-range integers, but the important part is that it can't just return an `a`.  After all, `aList ! 0` is not an integer!

Answer (score 8):

Yes. If you want a value that contains itself, you'll need a type that contains itself. This is no problem; for example, you might like rose trees, defined roughly like this in Data.Tree:

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a]
```

Now we can write:

```
recursiveTree = Node 1 [recursiveTree]
```

Answer (score 6):

This isn't possible with the list type in Haskell, since each element has to be of the same type, but you could create a data type to do it.  I'm not exactly sure why you'd want to, though.

```hs
data Nested a
    = Value a
    | List [Nested a]
    deriving (Eq, Show)

nested :: Nested Int
nested = List [nested, Value 1]

(!) :: Nested a -> Int -> Nested a
(!) (Value _) _ = undefined
(!) (List xs) n = xs !! n

main = print $ nested ! 0 ! 0 ! 1
```

This will print out `Value 1`, and this structure could be of some use, but I'd imagine it's pretty limited.

Comment: @bheklir It would be similar to a (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), but it would be defined recursively.

Comment: It turns out that it's also possible to define them in a mutually recursive way as well: http://ideone.com/4Wqniw

Comment: @AndersonGreen You missed a `List` in your example (http://ideone.com/bRRf32), but yes, it is possible.  The other nice thing (if I'm right, someone correct me if I'm wrong) is that this structure is actually recursive, `nested` and `nestedTwo` would actually take up constant memory.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: I've created an n-dimensional Quadtree-like structure a while back (and never really finished it). I'm not sure if the source code is a good read or useful to you, but it's [here](https://github.com/PaulVisschers/region-trie/blob/master/src/Data/RegionTrie.hs) if you want to check it out.

Comment: ExistentialQuantification, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

There were several answers from "yes you can" to "no you absolutely cannot". Well, both are right, because all of them address different aspects of your question.

One other way to add "array" to itself, is permit a list of anything.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data T = forall a. T a
arr :: [T]
arr = [T arr, T 1]
```

So, this adds arr to itself, but you cannot do anything else with it, except prove it is a valid construct and compile it.

Since Haskell is strongly typed, accessing list elements gives you T, and you could extract the contained value. But what is the type of that value? It is "forall a. a" - can be any type, which in essence means there are no functions at all that can do anything with it, not even print, because that would require a function that can convert any type a to String. Note that this is not specific to Haskell - even in dynamic languages the problem exists; there is no way to figure out the type of `arr !! 1`, you only assume it is a Int. What makes Haskell different to that other language, is that it does not let you use the function unless you can explain the type of the expression.

Other examples here define inductive types, which is not exactly what you are asking about, but they show the tractable treatment of self-referencing.

---

And here is how you could actually make a sensible construct:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data T = forall a. Show a => T a

instance Show T where -- this also makes Show [T],
        -- because Show a => Show [a] is defined in standard library
  show (T x) = show x

arr :: [T]
arr = [T arr, T 1]

main = print $ arr !! 1
```

Now the inner value wrapped by T is restricted to be any instance of Show ("implementation of Show interface" in OOP parlance), so you can at least print the contents of the list.

Note that earlier we could not include arr in itself only because there was nothing common between a and [a]. But the latter example is a valid construct once you can determine what's the common operation that all the elements in the list support. If you can define such a function for [T], then you can include arr in the list of itself - this function determines what's common between certain kinds of a and [a].

Comment: Note, however, that your second `T` type is isomorphic to `String`, since all you can do with a `Show`able `a` is `show` it.  Thus, `arr = [T arr, T 1] :: [T]` is morally the same as `arr' = [show arr', show 1]`.  For more, see [Luke Palmer's post on the existential type class antipattern](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/).

Comment: @AntalS-Z good point. I am merely showing it is possible to add self-reference to the list.

Answer (score 0):

No. We could emulate:

```
data ValueRef a = Ref | Value a deriving Show

lref :: [ValueRef Int]
lref = [Value 2, Ref, Value 1]

getValue :: [ValueRef a] -> Int -> [ValueRef a]
getValue lref index = case lref !! index of
     Ref -> lref
     a -> [a]
```

and have results:

```
>getValue lref 0
[Value 2]
>getValue lref 1
[Value 2,Ref,Value 1]
```

Sure, we could reuse `Maybe a` instead of `ValueRef a`