# Split Function - cannot construct the infinite type

Tags: haskell

The following code fails to compile:

```
split :: Char -> String -> [String]
split x ys = split' x ys [] 
              where split' _  [] acc = acc
                    split' x (z:zs) acc  
                     | x == z    = acc : split' x zs []
                     | otherwise = split' x zs (z:acc)
```

Compile-time error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Split.hs, interpreted )

Split.hs:5:36:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]
    In the first argument of `(:)', namely `acc'
    In the expression: acc : split' x zs []
    In an equation for split':
        split' x (z : zs) acc
          | x == z = acc : split' x zs []
          | otherwise = split' x zs (z : acc)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I read through this helpful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795317/why-does-this-haskell-code-produce-the-infinite-type-error), but I'm not seeing my mistake.

Comment: In `split'`, the type of `acc` is `[String]`, so in `z:acc` tyhe type of `z` must be `String`… it clearly isn't.

Comment: As was mentioned in the first comment on the linked post, a good tip is to add more type signatures (i.e. for `split'` in this case). When the compiler knows what type you *think* the function should be, it can usually locate your actual error more precisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posted code defined `split'` returning `acc` in one case and `acc : <<something>>` in another case. The compiler message states that, if `a0` is the type of `acc`, since both cases must return the same type it should be `a0 = [a0]`. Since no type can satisfy this equation (e.g. `String` is not `[String]`), the compiler complains with a type error.

A fix could then be to return a list containing `acc` is *both* cases. That is:

```
split :: Char -> String -> [String]
split x ys = split' x ys [] 
              where split' _  [] acc = [acc]             -- changed
                    split' x (z:zs) acc  
                     | x == z    = acc : split' x zs []
                     | otherwise = split' x zs (z:acc)
```

As a style note, since `x` is kept the same in each recursive call, there is no actual need for that parameter.

```
split :: Char -> String -> [String]
split x ys = split' ys [] 
              where split' [] acc = [acc]
                    split' (z:zs) acc  
                     | x == z    = acc : split' zs []
                     | otherwise = split' zs (z:acc)
```

The code is now type safe, but it still contains a bug:

```
> split 'a' "123a1234a"
["321","4321",""]
```

This is because the code "pops" characters from the string and "pushes" them in `acc`, so they end up being reversed. The fix is then easy:

```
split :: Char -> String -> [String]
split x ys = split' ys [] 
              where split' :: String -> String -> [String]
                    split' [] acc = [reverse acc]
                    split' (z:zs) acc  
                     | x == z    = reverse acc : split' zs []
                     | otherwise = split' zs (z:acc)
```

In this last revision I also added a type signature for the worker function, to document its code.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and pointing out the bug. Would you consider it correct for `split` to show `""` for a trailing character that matches the value on which to split? Such as your `split 'a' "123a1234a" example

Comment: @KevinMeredith Yes, I would consider it correct with the trailing `""`. This is because I see the `'a'` as a field separator, and not as a field terminator. Both are reasonable options, though, so it's hard to say which is the "correct" semantics for `split`.

Comment: That's exactly how [Data.List.Split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.1.1/docs/Data-List-Split.html)'s `splitOn` behaves: `ghci> splitOn "a" "AAAaBBBa"
| ["AAA","BBB",""]`