# Cannot construct inifnite type

Tags: haskell, fold

```
data Prop = a | b | c | d 
      deriving (Show, Eq)

data Wrapper =
      Wtail
      | Wrap prop
      | Mrappe Wrapper Wrapper
      deriving (Show, Eq)


fold_wrap :: (a -> a -> a) -> (Prop -> a) -> a -> Wrapper -> a

fold_wrap v x z (Mrappe l r)   = v ( v(v x z l) v(v x z r) )
fold_wrap v x z (Wrap f)       = x f 
fold_warp v x z (Wtail )       = z
```

I'm getting the following error with the above code:

```
ghc mast.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( mast.hs, mast.o )

mast.hs:13:39: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ Prop -> a
    • In the first argument of ‘v’, namely ‘x’
      In the first argument of ‘v’, namely ‘(v x z l)’
      In the first argument of ‘v’, namely ‘(v (v x z l) v (v x z r))’
    • Relevant bindings include
        z :: a (bound at mast.hs:13:15)
        x :: Prop -> a (bound at mast.hs:13:13)
        v :: a -> a -> a (bound at mast.hs:13:11)
        fold_mast :: (a -> a -> a) -> (Prop -> a) -> a -> Wrapper -> a
          (bound at mast.hs:13:1)
   |
13 | fold_mast v x z (Wrapper l r)  = v ( v(v x z l) v(v x z r) )
   |                                       ^
```

I've looked at:

[Why does this Haskell code produce the "infinite type" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795317/why-does-this-haskell-code-produce-the-infinite-type-error)

And if I understand correctly I cannot put my `v` function into my `fold_wrap` as it would allow infinite recursion.

The method `fold_wrap` should fold the treelike structure `Wrapper`, where `wtail` should point to a preconfigured constant value, `Wrap` has a value and `Mrappe` is what enables the data structure to be tree like.

My question is:

How do I avoid this "cannot construct the infinite type" error ?

Comment: `Prop`'s data constructors should start with an upper case letter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks wrong

```
fold_wrap v x z (Mrappe l r)   = v ( v(v x z l) v(v x z r) )
```

`v` takes two `a` arguments, and `x, z, l` are *three* arguments instead. Moreover `x, l` have not type `a`. 
Indeed, `x` has type `Prop -> a`, and equating `a ~ Prop -> a` causes the invalid "infinite" type.

You instead want to recurse there:

```
fold_wrap v x z (Mrappe l r)   = v (fold_wrap v x z l) (fold_wrap v x z r)
```